# The problem about move_uploaded_file() function in php

Tags: php, upload, file-upload, filesystems

I ran the code in apache localhost and also tried in my host. In both of them, the method moved the file but the file seemed 0kb.

Here is the code:

if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

```
    if($_FILES['profile_foto']['size']>0&&$_FILES['profile_foto']['size']<102400){

        $image_extension=explode("/",$_FILES['profile_foto']['type']);

        if($image_extension[1]!="jpeg")
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('The extension of the profile image must be jpeg!!!')</script>";

        else{

            if($_POST['image_id']==""){

                $image_id= md5(uniqid());

                $_FILES['profile_foto']['name']="tempo/".$image_id.".jpg";

                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profile_foto']['temp_name'],$_FILES['profile_foto']['name']);

                list($width,$height)=getimagesize("tempo/".$image_id.".jpg");

                if($width<=0||$width>170||$height<=0||$height>200){

                    $myFile="tempo/".$image_id.".jpg";
                    $fh=fopen($myFile,'w') or die("The File could not be opened!!!");
                    fclose($fh);
                    unlink($myFile);

                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('The width of your profile image must be less than 170 px, the height must be less than 200 px!!!')</script>";

                }
                else
                    $_POST['image_id']=$fotograf_id;

            }
            else{

                $image_id= md5(uniqid());

                $_FILES['profile_foto']['name']="tempo/".$image_id.".jpg";

                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profile_foto']['temp_name'],$_FILES['profile_foto']['name']);

                list($width,$height)=getimagesize("tempo/".$image_id.".jpg");

                if($width<=0||$width>170||$height<=0||$height>200){

                    $myFile="tempo/".$image_id.".jpg";
                    $fh=fopen($myFile,'w') or die("The File could not be opened!!!");
                    fclose($fh);
                    unlink($myFile);

                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('The width of your profile image must be less than 170 px, the height must be less than 200 px!!!')</script>";

                }
                else{
                    $image_will_be_deleted=$_POST['image_id'];

                    $myFile="tempo/".$image_will_be_deleted.".jpg";
                    $fh=fopen($myFile,'w') or die("The File cannot be opened!!!");
                    fclose($fh);
                    unlink($myFile);
                    $_POST['image_id']=$image_id;

                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('The size of the profile image must be less than 100 kb!!!')</script>";

}
```

Comment: please specify the environment the code is running, O.S, hosting or VPS, etc.

Comment: @Türker instead of re-tagging your question, show some code! And welcome to SO.

Comment: Without the code I might be shooting in the night, but make sure the file you're moving exists, 
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }

Comment: You are creating empty files under certain conditions. I am suspecting you are seeing one of those, not an actual uploaded image. What are those empty files good for?

Comment: I checked if the FILE array is not empty and the file uploaded with no error. There was no problem uploading the file to FILE array but when I tried to use move_uploded_file() it moves the file to where I want and with the name that I want but the size of it seems 0 kb.

Comment: Perhaps you are moving the file from the wrong place?

Answer (score 5):

You've posted about 50 lines of code when you claim only one isn't working. Strip out the 50 lines of code and replace it with:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profile_foto']['temp_name'],'tempo/test.jpg');
```

....and find out what happens when you try to upload a file.

C.

Comment: +1 for this approach. Always start with simple step, make it work, then add new feature one at a time, test to make sure it work, repeat. Start with a complex code will make you lost when finding bugs. You can also separate complex function into separate functions, like checking size, checking file type, doing post processing, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
$_FILES['profile_foto']['temp_name']
```

ought to be

```
$_FILES['profile_foto']['tmp_name']
```

in the statement

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profile_foto']['temp_name'], $_FILES['profile_foto']['name']);
```

Comment: You solved the problem thank you. The reason was I should use tmp_name instead of temp_name. Thank you very much for figuring that out from all of those complex algoritims.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a little function to conveniently resize you photos to whatever see below. if only $size1 is provided the image will be resized using this as its largest dimension, otherwise if $size2 is provided the image will be resized proportionally using $size1 as its largest dimension and then the rest is cropped. Might make it easier than your ($width<=0||$width>170||$height<=0||$height>200):

```
function resizeImg($name, $extension, $size1, $size2) {
    if (preg_match('/jpg|jpeg/',$extension)){
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($name);
    }
    if (preg_match('/gif/',$extension)){
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($name);
    }

    $old_width = imageSX($image);
    $old_height = imageSY($image);
    $old_aspect_ratio = $old_width/$old_height; 

    if($size2 == 0){
        $new_aspect_ratio = $old_aspect_ratio;
        if($old_width > $old_height){
            $new_width = $size1;
            $new_height = $new_width / $old_aspect_ratio;
        } else {
            $new_height = $size1;
            $new_width = $new_height * $old_aspect_ratio;
        }
    } elseif($size2 > 0){
        $new_aspect_ratio = $size1/$size2;
        //for landscape potographs
        if($old_aspect_ratio >= $new_aspect_ratio) {
            $new_width = $size1;
            $new_height = $size2;
            $x1 = round(($old_width - ($old_width * ($new_aspect_ratio/$old_aspect_ratio)))/2);
            $old_width = round($old_width * ($new_aspect_ratio/$old_aspect_ratio));
            $y1 = 0;
            //for portrait photographs
        } else{
            $new_width = $size1;
            $new_height = $size2;
            $x1 = 0;
            $y1 = round(($old_height/2) - ($new_height/2));
            $old_height = round($old_width/$new_aspect_ratio);
        }
    }

    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    imagecopyresized($new_image, $image, 0, 0, $x1, $y1, $new_width, $new_height, $old_width, $old_height);

    return $new_image;
}
```